# How can I successfully login with root after running mysql_secure_installation?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am currently unable to login as root on mysql and I am not quite sure about what's going on. Here's what happened:

I ran `mysql_secure_installation` as recommended, to secure my mysql installation. Afterwards, I typed the default root password that was asked and then I entered:

- No to setting a password for root
- Yes on removing anonymous users
- Yes on disallowing remote root login
- Yes on removing the test database and access to it
- Yes on reloading privilege tables

After completing this process, I tried accessing mysql with `mysql -u root -p` (entered the default password) and received this message:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Do you have any ideas on what might have went wrong?

I also tried resetting the root password by starting mysql with `--skip-grant-tables`, but I am still not able to login.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `mysql 14.14` (LAMP stack).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but the main answer is outdated and did not solve my issue.
Below my steps for future reference if anybody is having similar problems.

Stop mysql if it's running

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

Start mysql in safe mode

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
```

**If you get the error**
*"mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists"*
Just create that folder:

```
$ mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
$ chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Open a new terminal window and log into mysql service + select mysql database:

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql;
```

Set new password for root user:

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('new-password') where user='root';
```

Flush privileges and exit mysql:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
```

Stop the safemode mysql (from the second terminal, you will see it stop in the first terminal)

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Restart mysql

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

You should be able to use the root user with password now to login to mysql/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

**CentOS/Redhat:**

From what I read in docs, when you run `mysql_secure_installation`, a temporary root password is generated and is stored in some log file.

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

During the packages installation, you get a prompt asking for the root password. If you don’t set it up, MySQL’s root user is created without a password. We can read the following line in package installation output:

Shell

> 2016-05-16T07:27:21.532619Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with
>   an empty password ! Please consider switching off the
>   --initialize-insecure option.

but it is configured with the auth_socket plugin. You will only be able to connect using the UNIX socket, therefore any attempt to connect using your local IP or the network fails. Later on, you can change the password to allow connections from the network (as explained in this blog post).

[Source](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/18/where-is-the-mysql-5-7-root-password/)

All we can do now is to see the root password. Lets change the root password since you cannot understand hashed password even if we can see it:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
```

then run mysql in a new terminal

```
mysql -u root
```

and run the following query, after changing the password

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

quit the mysql safe mode and start mysql service by

```
mysqladmin shutdown
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just looked on `/var/log/` folder, there is a log file called `mysql.log` but it's empty.

Comment: Hi @Thanos can I know your mysql version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: Hmm, still can't figure this out. From my understanding, this is related with the auth_socket plugin?

Comment: If you typed nothing when mysql has prompted you for password then I think we should focus more on auth_socket plugin problem. This blog might help you https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Comment: Alright, I think I've done a little progress here. I have changed the plugin for the root user to mysql_native_password and the password to a new one (also confirmed that it's set), but I still can't login. Maybe there is something else blocking that?

Comment: @Thanos, please check the update and let me know If it didn't work!!

Comment: Alright, I can try that tomorrow and I will let you know.

Comment: I changed the root password with the commands you mentioned above, however after executing `mysqladmin shutdown` I receive these error messages: `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`. I also tried `service mysql restart` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126641/discussion-between-thanos-and-shiva-shinde).

Answer (score 0):

## just run this script by root , you need custormize you password

```
mysqlpassword=password
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password "$mysqlpassword"
#configure mysql login privileges
echo "grant all privileges on *.* to root@\"localhost\" identified by \"$mysqlpassword\";show databases;" |mysql -u root  -p$mysqlpassword
```